# RouteModelBinding with slug and id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Has anyone ever tryed if this works in laravel:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return ['id','slug'];
}
```

so anyone can RouteModelBind by slug or by id?

Comment: Look at https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: To improve this question you could specify what kind of error you get when running it, what is your expected outcome and maybe how are you planning to use the results of these lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to overwrite the resolveRouteBinding method of your model:

For example like this:

```
public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
{
    if (is_numeric($value)) {
        return $this->findOrFail($id);
    }

    return $this->where('slug', $value)->firstOrFail();
}
```